# Honeywell TH1100DH1004 - temperature signal

Tags: sensor, hobbyist

Is it possible to have this (non programmable ) thermostat communicate only a constant temperature reading regardless of what the sensor senses?

My understanding is that it communicates a value set by user lets say 66 F once, and it compares that value to the temperature sensor readings. sends a "turn on heater" command if the temperature drops below the user set.  It stores the user set value until it is changed again.

Is it possible to somehow block this signal? such as taping a pin or cutting a wire inside? The installation manual doesn't describe which pin does this

Comment: What are you trying to do? Fix the temperature threshold?

Comment: @DKNguyen the objective is to when user sets  a value x, it holds that value, and any further user changes are not registered. lets say I set X , the themp sensor still sense X+1 and X-1. Now I set value Y. But I don't want this value Y to be registered. I want the thermostat to think the requested  value is still X ( hence question about  blocking signal) , I have no experience with HVAC , let me know if it makes sense

Answer (score 0):

The Honeywell thermostat is reed relay controlled.  You can pull it out of the wall to disconnect it or any other way as it activates heat or A/C by contact closure to a 24V + relay coil load.